# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE to use lookaround or AND ignoring the order

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to find a match with a given list of search parameters appearing anywhere in the given string. The search parameters can be OR or AND. REGEXP_LIKE with REPLACE works fine with OR (|) but not able to do for AND. Here is an example of OR:

`select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('BCR081', REPLACE ('BCR;081', ';', '|'));` 
--works

`select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('BCR081', '(' || REPLACE ('BCR;081', ';', ').*?(') || ')');`

 -- Works when they are in order but order shouldn't matter.

`select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('BCR081', '(' || REPLACE ('081;BCR', ';', ').*?(') || ')');` 
--I need this to work.

Is there something equivalent to

```
select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('BCR081', REPLACE ('BCR;081', ';', '&'));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried (look ahead?):

```
select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('BCR081','(?=' || REPLACE ('081;BCR', ';', ')(?=') || ')');
```

**Note:** The above is an example only, we can have anywhere from 1-20 search parameters. Also can't use the contains clause as it will throw too many results error.

Comment: Use `regexp_like() and regexp_like()`

Comment: Yes but I will have to repeat it for may be 20 times if there are 20 parameters.

Comment: you want to search for 20 parameters(max), in some random order?

Comment: A string containing all the 20 (max) parameters in any order, just like contains but contains throws an Oracle error when too many rows returned

Answer (score 0):

We can *tokenise* the search string and look for one by one, by virtually generating rows.

```
with my_data as
(
  select 'BCR081' as str , 'BCR;081' as pattern from dual
),
pattern_table as
(
  select str, regexp_substr(pattern,'[^;]+',1,level) as pattern
  from my_data
  connect by level <= regexp_count(pattern,';') + 1
)
SELECT DECODE(
               COUNT(DECODE(
                           INSTR(a.str,b.pattern),
                           0,
                           null,
                           1)
                    ),
                0,
               'no match',
               'match'
             ) as result
 FROM my_data a, pattern_table b
 WHERE a.str = b.str
 GROUP BY a.str;
```